# Shape.ShadowEffect property (Direction and Angle) VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on Excel 2013. I need the Shape.ShadowEffect property (Direction and Angle) VBA Code

[image]

VBA code:

```
'Shadow ---> Presets
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Oval Background")).Select
'Shadow ---> Presets ---> Outer
With Selection.ShapeRange.Shadow
    .Type = msoShadow23 'msoShadow23
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Style = msoShadowStyleOuterShadow
    .Blur = 15 'Blur 15 pt
    .OffsetX = 0.7071067812
    .OffsetY = 0.7071067812
    .RotateWithShape = msoFalse
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 0.799999997 'Transparency 65%
    .Size = 104 'Size 104%
    .Direction = 4 '4 pt
    .Angle = 0.9 '90 Degree
End With
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: .Direction = 4 and .Angle = 0.9  "VBA Code Shape.ShadowEffect property not working"